# Using grep to find keywords, and then list the following characters until the next ; character

Tags: regex, grep, osx-yosemite

I have a long list of chemical conditions in the following form:

```
0.2M sodium acetate; 0.3M ammonium thiosulfate;
```

The molarities can be listed in various ways:

```
x.xM, x.x M, x M
```

where the number of `x` digits vary. I want to do two things, select those numbers using grep, and then list only the following characters until `;`. So if I select `0.2M` in the example above, I want to be able to list `sodium acetate`.

For selecting, I have tried the following:

```
grep '[0-9]*.[0-9]*[[:space:]]*M' file
```

so that there are arbitrary number of digits and spaces, but it always ends with `M`. The problem is, it also selects the following:

```
0.05MRbCl+MgCl2;
```

I am not quite sure why this is selected. Ideally, I would want `0.05M` to be selected, and then list `RbCl+MgCl2`. How can I achieve this?

(The system is OS X Yosemite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches that because:
`[0-9]*` matches `0`
`.` matches any character (this is the `.` in this case, but you probably meant to escape it)
`[0-9]*` matches `05`
`[[:space:]]*` matches the empty string between `05` and `M`
`M` matches `M`

As for how to do what you want: I think that if you don't want the numbers to be printed with the output, this would require either a lookbehind assertion or the ability to print a specific capture group, which it sounds like OS X's `grep` doesn't support. You could use a similar approach with a slightly more powerful tool, though:

```
$ cat test.txt 
0.2M sodium acetate; 0.3M ammonium thiosulfate;
0.05MRbCl+MgCl2;
1.23M dihydrogen monoxide;
45 M xenon quadroxide;

$ perl -ne 'while (/([0-9]*\.)?[0-9]+\s*M\s*([^;]+)/g) { print "$2\n"; }' test.txt 
sodium acetate
ammonium thiosulfate
RbCl+MgCl2
dihydrogen monoxide
xenon quadroxide
```

Written out, that regex is:
`([0-9]*\.)?` optionally, some digits and a decimal point
`[0-9]+` one or more digits
`\s*M\s*` the letter M, with spacing around it
`([^;]+)` all the characters up until the next semicolon (the thing you want to print)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `gensub()` and `\s`:

```
$ awk -vRS=';\\s*' -vm='0.2M' 'm==gensub(/\s*([0-9.]+)\s*M.*/,"\\1M","")' file
0.2M sodium acetate

$ awk -vRS=';\\s*' -vm='0.05M' 'm==gensub(/\s*([0-9.]+)\s*M.*/,"\\1M","")' file
0.05MRbCl+MgCl2
```